# Make dropdown visible

Tags: html, css

I have this navigation bar with some text. As long as the `navbar` has `overflow: hidden`, it has a `background-color`, the text is not overflowing the `navbar`, etc. and everything is fine. **But**, with `overflow: hidden`, the content of the dropdown isn't shown. Is there any way to make it show?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fcf3e3;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #f9eedd;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -6px #c4b29c;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 20%;
  z-index: 10;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: block;
  color: #8e8275;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 1.6vmin;
  padding: 1.5vmin 1.3vmin 1.5vmin 0;
  margin: 1.3vmin 1.3vmin 1.3vmin 0;
}

.navbar li.links {
  float: left;
}

.navbar li.rechts {
  float: right;
}

.navbar li a:hover:not(.active) {
  color: #252118;
}

.navbar li a.active {
  text-decoration: underline
}

.navbar .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fef6e9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0.1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 10;
}

.navbar .dropdown-content a {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1.5vmin 1.3vmin;
}

.navbar .dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f7eedc;
}

.navbar .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
  <li class="links"><a href="index.html">Lorem</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown links"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">ipsum▾</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">dolor</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">sit</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">amet</a></li>
  <li class="rechts"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Lorem</a></li>
  <li class="rechts"><a href="javascript:void(0)">dolor</a></li>
</ul>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus non urna ac odio iaculis pharetra. Suspendisse bibendum sit amet neque id lacinia. Donec at suscipit lorem. Nulla id luctus enim. Vivamus rhoncus tincidunt turpis, vel eleifend urna. Donec
  vestibulum metus et massa ullamcorper, eu feugiat mauris suscipit. Etiam sit amet iaculis neque. Maecenas vitae nibh in ipsum facilisis vulputate sed sit amet ex. Pellentesque molestie lacinia tellus.</p>
```

Comment: Can you share the Javscript code and if you are using any frameworks?

Comment: There're no Javascript codes

Comment: I was able to make a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/x2dbvmp5/1/, can you edit this fiddle and show us how the dropdown becomes visible? There needs to be some kind of javascript to show the dropdown somehow?

Comment: When you remove overflow:hidden it becomes visible

Comment: I made the dropdown based on this; https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give your `navbar` a `height` and remove the `overflow: hidden` it works fine.
You can play around with the `height` but I just used `50px` as example.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fcf3e3;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #f9eedd;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -6px #c4b29c;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 20%;
  z-index: 10;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
}

.navbar li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: block;
  color: #8e8275;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 1.6vmin;
  padding: 1.5vmin 1.3vmin 1.5vmin 0;
  margin: 1.3vmin 1.3vmin 1.3vmin 0;
}

.navbar li.links {
  float: left;
}

.navbar li.rechts {
  float: right;
}

.navbar li a:hover:not(.active) {
  color: #252118;
}

.navbar li a.active {
  text-decoration: underline
}

.navbar .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fef6e9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0.1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 10;
}

.navbar .dropdown-content a {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1.5vmin 1.3vmin;
}

.navbar .dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f7eedc;
}

.navbar .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
  <li class="links"><a href="index.html">Lorem</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown links"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">ipsum▾</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">dolor</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">sit</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">amet</a></li>
  <li class="rechts"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Lorem</a></li>
  <li class="rechts"><a href="javascript:void(0)">dolor</a></li>
</ul>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus non urna ac odio iaculis pharetra. Suspendisse bibendum sit amet neque id lacinia. Donec at suscipit lorem. Nulla id luctus enim. Vivamus rhoncus tincidunt turpis, vel eleifend urna. Donec
  vestibulum metus et massa ullamcorper, eu feugiat mauris suscipit. Etiam sit amet iaculis neque. Maecenas vitae nibh in ipsum facilisis vulputate sed sit amet ex. Pellentesque molestie lacinia tellus.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove your `overflow: hidden` and add `display: none`, so your dropdown doesn't show.
When you `hover` the `li` with class dropdown you add `display: block` to show the dropdown.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fcf3e3;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #f9eedd;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -6px #c4b29c;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 20%;
  z-index: 10;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.navbar li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: block;
  color: #8e8275;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 1.6vmin;
  padding: 1.5vmin 1.3vmin 1.5vmin 0;
  margin: 1.3vmin 1.3vmin 1.3vmin 0;
}

.navbar li.links {
  float: left;
}

.navbar li.rechts {
  float: right;
}

.navbar li a:hover:not(.active) {
  color: #252118;
}

.navbar li a.active {
  text-decoration: underline
}

.navbar .dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fef6e9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0.1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
  /* add this and remove overflow hidden*/
}

.navbar .dropdown-content a {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1.5vmin 1.3vmin;
}

.navbar .dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f7eedc;
}

.navbar .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover>div {
  display: block;
}


/* add this */
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
  <li class="links"><a href="index.html">Lorem</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown links"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">ipsum▾</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">dolor</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">sit</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">amet</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="rechts"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Lorem</a></li>
  <li class="rechts"><a href="javascript:void(0)">dolor</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

With the provided information you gave me in the comments, I was able to fix this for you by removing `overflow: hidden` and giving the `navbar` `position: fixed` instead of `position: sticky`. `overflow: hidden` forces the `div` to hide all elements that appear outside of it, so you can't keep it.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fcf3e3;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #f9eedd;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -6apx #c4b29c;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 20%;
  z-index: 10000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}

.navbar li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: block;
  color: #8e8275;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 1.6vmin;
  padding: 1.5vmin 1.3vmin 1.5vmin 0;
  margin: 1.3vmin 1.3vmin 1.3vmin 0;
}

.navbar li.links {
  float: left;
}

.navbar li.rechts {
  float: right;
}

.navbar li a:hover:not(.active) {
  color: #252118;
}

.navbar li a.active {
  text-decoration: underline
}

.navbar .dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fef6e9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0.1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 10;
}

.navbar .dropdown-content a {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1.5vmin 1.3vmin;
}

.navbar .dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f7eedc;
}

.navbar .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
  <li class="links"><a href="index.html">Lorem</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown links"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">ipsum▾</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">dolor</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">sit</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">amet</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="rechts"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Lorem</a></li>
  <li class="rechts"><a href="javascript:void(0)">dolor</a></li>
</ul>
```